# Gulp task/plugin to check CSS naming conventions

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I've taken over a legacy application and im trying to refactor and commonise the CSS naming standards.

I've noticed CSS class naming conventions are referred to in a variety of ways:

```
my-class-name
_my_class_name
myClassName
my-class_name
etc
```

Is there a Gulp task or/and plugin that searches all my HTML files, and produces a report of the various naming conventions?

Ideally I want all classes to follow: my-class-name

Comment: Specifically, I don't know, but you can check this out "gulp-purifycss"

Comment: That you want is to get all your html class attributes and change it to that convention my-class-name into your html ? Correct me if I'm wrong, not sure about what you want